# Lenovo ThinkPad Laptop Reboots without booting completely OR Shuts down randomly

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot, reboot

**Background**

Before this issue started, I was using Laptop and my laptop hung because of switching to battery from AC.

I had to force shutdown using power button. When I turned on laptop next time, I was faced with the issue.

**Technical Information**

```
OS: Windows 10, Kali Linux (Removed)
Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad W530
CPU: Intel Core i7-3720QM @2.60GHz
GPU: Nvidia Quadro K2000M
RAM: 8GB
```

When this problem first occurred, I had a dual boot system with Kali Linux and Windows 10. Initially, I wasn't even able to complete Automatic Startup Repair of Windows 10 OR boot via USB to repair computer using a windows 10 bootable USB.

I couldn't boot into Kali Linux either which suggest that it wasn't an OS issue.

Poking around in the BIOS, changing Boot Order Priority to "USB, CD, HDD" and switching to Diagnostic boot instead of Quick boot eventually allowed me to boot via USB. I went into recovery mode and opened up command prompt and ran:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

It worked and I was finally able to start windows 10. I removed the Kali Linux Partition and merged the unallocated Kali Linux Partition into an existing Drive.

This Way I got rid of Kali Linux and GRUB Bootloader. I had thought that GRUB was somehow causing problems.

When I switched to Quick Boot and Changed Boot Priority to "HDD, USB, CD", I got the same issue. Once again, it took some attempts after trying everything as I did initially to get it working.

I have run all Lenovo Diagnostic tests (RAM, HDD) and everything was OK.

However, now I get random shutdowns and sometimes repeated boots. I can share the windows event log if that will help.

**Edit:** I have tried wiping HDD fully, reinstalling windows. Reseated RAMs. Removed CMOS.
I even used another HDD.
Regardless of whatever I tried, the issue is still same and there.
There's one thing confusing which is: why it reboots when booting OS and Does NOT Reboot while installing OS?

Comment: Run the Lenovo Hardware Diagnostics App and look for hardware errors.  Get Kaspersky TDSS Killer and look for a rootkit virus.

Comment: Oh, I actually did that all tests came OK. Let me add that to description

Comment: If hardware is good and you have these issues, you should back up and reinstall Windows.  I have Kali and one one machine it went bad because of Grub  (VM machine)

Comment: Lenovo Diagnostics work very well detecting hardware issues.  Try re-running the diagnostics.

Comment: Sorry for previous comment, I actually meant to say that
Given the background, It seems me to me that this is definitely NOT a Hardware issue. I am planning for a windows reinstall.

Comment: I posted an answer given your comments. Hopefully you will acknowledge.

Answer (score 0):

> Lenovo ThinkPad Laptop Reboots without booting completely OR Shuts
> down randomly

If hardware tests good  (Lenovo Hardware Diagnostics) and you have these issues, you should back up and reinstall Windows.

I have Kali and on one machine it went bad because of Grub (VM machine)

If you continue to have failures trying to reinstall Windows, there may be a hardware failure not uncovered by diagnostics.

Also contact Lenovo Support and ask them for the Recovery USB for your model. That may be the best way to reinstall Windows  if there is not a hardware issue (not clear at this point).

Comment: Thank for suggestion. I will try that.

Comment: I have tried wiping HDD fully, reinstalling windows. Reseated RAMs. Removed CMOS.
I even used another HDD.
Regardless of whatever I tried, the issue is still same and there.
There's one thing confusing which is: why it reboots when booting OS and Does NOT Reboot while installing OS?

Comment: There does appear to be a hardware issue of some sort.

Comment: I amended my answer to include obtaining a Recovery USB key from Lenovo Support. That is an excellent way to reinstall Windows. I do this fairly routinely.